# How to plot, in Javascript and on a D3.js line graph, real time time data coming from web socket messages via stomp.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, websocket, stomp

Using Javascript I need to invoke a web socket (using stomp.js ...), and plot the real time data on a D3.js line graph.

Here you are my actual code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Client Stomp 1</title>

   <style>
    body { font: 12px Arial;}

    path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
   </style>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>

   <!-- *** D3.js library inclusion ... *** -->
   <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script>
       var urlServer;
       var topics;

       // *** Service variable to interrupt te values visualization ...
       var i = 0;

       // *** The vector that will mantain the couple values  data - temperatura that there will be plotted in the line graph ...
       var dataLineGraph = [];

       // *** Setting the server and topic parameters ...
       urlServer = "ws://stream.smartdatanet.it/ws";
       topics = "/topic/output.arpa_rumore.4c5d7481-fa5e-4f2f-d26d-d4e8095b9dd2_s_01";

       // *** Create the stomp client and estabilish the connection ...
       // *** username and password are public
       client = Stomp.client(urlServer);
       client.connect("guest" , "Aekieh6F" , connectCallBack, errorCallback);

       plotLineGraph (dataLineGraph);

       // *** Manage the connection ...
       function connectCallBack(x) {
           client.subscribe(topics, messageCallback);
           if (i < 1) {alert("Make the connection !")}
           i = i + 1;
       }

       // *** Manage the connection error...
       function errorCallback(x) {
           if (i < 1) {alert("Connection error !")}
           i = i + 1;
       }

       // *** Manage the message callback...
      function messageCallback(x) {
           if (i < 5) {
             alert("First messages sent form the platform! To see the others open the web browser console !!!");

             // *** Convert the body message in JSON format ...
             var theJson = JSON.parse(x.body);

             // *** Alert the time and the b_6300_Hz value ...
             //alert(theJson.values[0].time + " - " + theJson.values[0].components.b_6300_Hz);

             // *** Alert the time and the b_6300_Hz value ...
             time = theJson.values[0].time;

             // *** Hardcoded but it's only to test the date parsing ...
             day = time.substring(8,10);
             //alert ("Day = " + day);
             month = time.substring(5,7);
             //alert ("month = " + month);
             year = time.substring(0,4);
             //alert ("Year = " + year);
             hour = time.substring(11,13);
             //alert ("Hour = " + hour);
             minutes = time.substring(14,16);
             //alert ("Minutes = " + minutes);
             seconds = time.substring(17,19);
             //alert ("Seconds= " + seconds);

//             formattedDate = (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear() + "-" + (dt.getHours()) + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
             formattedDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + "-" + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

             value = theJson.values[0].components.b_6300_Hz;

//             2016-07-01T15:18:31+0200 - 50.2
             alert ("formattedDate = " + formattedDate);

             dataLineGraph.push({time: formattedDate, value:value});
           }

           i = i + 1;
      }




      // *** Function for to draw the line graph ...
      function plotLineGraph (data) {
          // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
          var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
              width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
              height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

          // Set the ranges
          var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
          var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

          // Define the axes
          var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(5);
          var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5);

          // Define the line
          var valueline = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
              .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

          // Adds the svg canvas
          var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g")
                  .attr("transform",
                        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          // Parse the date / time
          var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S").parse;

          // Get the data
      //    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

              data.forEach(function(d) {
                  d.date = parseDate(d.time);
                  d.close = +d.value;
              });

              // Scale the range of the data
              x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
              y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

              // Add the valueline path.
              svg.append("path")
                  .attr("class", "line")
                  .attr("d", valueline(data));

              // Add the X Axis
              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                  .call(xAxis);

              // Add the Y Axis
              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .call(yAxis);

      //    });

      }


     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can copy / paste and try to execute ( ... shoud be work ...).

I'm able to consume messages from the stream as you can see from the alert or watching the web browser console but I don't know how to put these informations on a dynamic line graph like this one http://jsfiddle.net/peDzT/.

How may I add data in my dataLineGraph array on the line graph and how may I refresh it at every new data is added in my vector?

Note that the plotLineGraph funtions works if I use it with "static" data loaded one time.

Any suggestions / example will be appreciated !!!

Cesare

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070. Here's a straightforward example for having a live/updating graph. Hopefully you can understand that and then hook it up with the events you should be receiving from your stomp.js websocket connector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've cleaned up and refactored your code a good bit to show you an example implementation.  In it I'm plotting time vs. b_400_Hz since I'm not sure which signal you are after.  I've commented the code below pretty well, and it's runn-able, so just ask if you have any questions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Client Stomp 1</title>

  <style>
    body {
      font: 12px Arial;
    }
    
    path {
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2;
      fill: none;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: grey;
      stroke-width: 1;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>

  <!-- *** D3.js library inclusion ... *** -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var urlServer;
    var topics;

    // *** The vector that will mantain the couple values  data - temperatura that there will be plotted in the line graph ...
    var dataLineGraph = [];

    // *** Setting the server and topic parameters ...
    urlServer = "ws://stream.smartdatanet.it/ws";
    topics = "/topic/output.arpa_rumore.4c5d7481-fa5e-4f2f-d26d-d4e8095b9dd2_s_01";

    // *** Create the stomp client and estabilish the connection ...
    // *** username and password are public
    client = Stomp.client(urlServer);
    client.connect("guest", "Aekieh6F", connectCallBack, function(){});

    // *** Manage the connection ...
    function connectCallBack(x) {
      client.subscribe(topics, messageCallback);
    }
    
    function compare(a,b) {
      if (a.time < b.time)
        return -1;
      if (a.time > b.time)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    // parse the times from the server
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").parse;
    
    // *** Manage the message callback...
    function messageCallback(x) {

      // *** Convert the body message in JSON format ...
      var theJson = JSON.parse(x.body);

      // grab the values of interest
      dataLineGraph.push({
        time: parseDate(theJson.values[0].time),
        value: +theJson.values[0].components.b_400_Hz
      });
      
      // make sure we stay sorted
      dataLineGraph.sort(compare);
      
      plotLineGraph();
    }

    // intial graph setup
    setupGraph();

    // keep reference to these variables from setupGraph
    var valueline, x, y, xAxisG, yAxisG, line;
    
    function setupGraph() {
      // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
      var margin = {
          top: 30,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 50
        },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // Set the ranges
      x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
      y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

      // Define the line
      valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          console.log(d)
          return x(d.time);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        });

      // Adds the svg canvas
      var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      // Add the X Axis
      xAxisG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

      // Add the Y Axis
      yAxisG = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis");

      line = svg.append("path");
    }


    // *** Function for to draw the line graph ...
    function plotLineGraph() {

      // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(dataLineGraph, function(d) {
        return d.time;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(dataLineGraph, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })]);
 
      // transistion axis
      xAxisG
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));
        
      yAxisG
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease("linear")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

      // change the line
      line.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("d", valueline(dataLineGraph));
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed !! Great reply with runnable and detailed code. You made me save a lot of time. Thank you for the time you spent to answer